# FCM server api is returning a response of 200 in expo app, but the notification never gets received

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

Firebase cloud messaging server api(https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) is returning a response of 200 in expo app, but the notification never gets received on any of the devices that the app build is installed in, but it works perfectly when i use the firebase console.

Here is the function for sending the notification:

```
const sendNotification = async (
    pushToken: any,
    title: string,
    message: string
  ) => {
    //sendPushNotification(pushToken, title, message);

    await fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `key=<myTokenKey>`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        to: pushToken,
        priority: "normal",
        data: {
          experienceId: "@retemember/rete",
          scopeKey: "@retemember/rete",
          title,
          message,
        },
      }),
    });
  };
```